# Ground wire light switch to outlet

Tags: switch, receptacle, grounding

[image][image]I am trying to install a [Leviton IPS02-1LW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B361NJM)  (Amazon link) motion sensing light switch. However, my current light switch does not have a ground. Can I run a ground wire from a nearby outlet, or could that cause issues?

Comment: Model #? Picture of switch box?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box, and the make and model of the motion sensor you are trying to install please?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Leviton-IPS02-1LW-300-Watt-Incandescent-Occupancy/dp/B00B361NJM/ref=sr_1_9?dchild=1&keywords=light+switch+sensor+motion&qid=1595723032&sr=8-9 is the switch I am trying to use. If needed I can post a picture. But what I wanted to do was simply use an existing outlet's ground and run the wire from there to the light switch.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. It's always best to [edit] your post to include info that people ask for - sometimes the comments get a bit lengthy and info like that can get lost. I've added it for you to make things easier. Please take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with how the site works, and if you'll browse through the [help], you'll learn about how comments work and can sometimes disappear.

Comment: Please post a picture of the inside of the box, there might be a way out of it without having to retrofit a ground wire

Comment: picture added..

Comment: Just to be clear you can connect to a ground wire in a gfci, but aren't allowed to connect anything to the ground screw on the receptacle if the gfci was a replacement for an ungrounded two wire receptacle.

Comment: Current code allows a ground wire to  from any location as long as they are fed from the same location!

Comment: Can you please post a picture clearly showing the *inside* of the switch box?  Right now, we have no idea if *neutral* is available there, and that's a bigger deal than having ground available...

Comment: Gotta say, the box for that light switch was really wedged in there.

Comment: Added close up view of switch. And yea I know the box was really wedged in there. Several things I keep finding around the house that are really suspect. Also house was built in 99 and that is the original switch and outlet.

Comment: Where do the two black wires exiting the left of the switch box lead?  Something really weird is going on there....

Answer (score 1):

The NEC allows connecting to a ground from another circuit if that circuit originates in the same panel.

If they do originate in different panels or a subpanel the Code also allows connecting to any point on the grounding electrode system, the grounding electrode conductor, the ground bar in the panel where the circuit originates, or the grounded conductor in the service enclosure. (NEC 250.130, free clunky access the NEC at https://www.nfpa.org/codes-and-standards/all-codes-and-standards/list-of-codes-and-standards/detail?code=70 )

Comment: So as long as it is all from the same circuit breaker panel I am good?

Comment: Yes. I really expected that was the case as most houses have a single panel, but it is best to answer to accurately answer for all installations so others don't mis-state the actual rules.

Comment: Thank you i really appreciate the help in this. I was thinking I could, but I am by no means an electrician and wanted to get others opinions who are far more well versed than I in this. Electricity is one of the things I do not want to mess around with in terms of winging it.

Answer (score -1):

"Special" switches, including motion sensors, dimmers, smart switches, timers, etc. often need power even when the lights (or other controlled items) are off. There are 4 ways they can get this power:

- Battery

This is simplest - no issue of "what wires are available" - but generally least desirable because of the need to periodically replace batteries.

- Neutral

This is easy in *new* construction, because code now generally requires either a neutral in each switch box or an easy way (i.e., wires in conduit) to add a new neutral. With a neutral available, the special device can get mains power just like anything else.

In some old installations, neutral will be available. But in some cases, particularly with *switch loops*, there is no neutral available. You can't just "add a neutral" if the existing wires are in a cable - you have to replace the cable.

- Leakage

Some devices will get their power by leaking a little bit through the circuit in the "off" position. This works great with incandescent bulbs. With fluorescent bulbs it often doesn't work at all. With LEDs, because they need so little power, they will often either glow dimly (if they are dimmable) or blink (if they are not dimmable) in the "off" position, which is generally not desirable.

- Ground

The advantage of ground is that it *should* be everywhere. However, this can cause problems with GFCI protection. Lighting circuits generally don't need to be GFCI protected, but often they are either because "everything has GFCI" or a circuit is shared between lighting and receptacles that need GFCI (e.g., in a bathroom). GFCI detects the difference between hot & neutral. If some of your power goes from hot to ground, that can trip the GFCI, even though in this case it is legitimate and not an actual safety problem.

The second problem with ground is, as you have found, that it is not always available. However, ground *should* be available - you just have to know where to look. If you don't see an actual green or bare ground wire, you might have:

- A metal box connected to armored cable or conduit. In this case, you can get a grounding screw with a pigtail and screw that into the metal box to provide a ground wire for your switch.
- A ground wire that wasn't technically needed before and snipped off. Shouldn't happen, but sometimes it does. If you have cable, take a look at the end where the black & white wires come out and see if there is a ground wire in there too. If there is, *and if you have enough excess cable*, strip some of the outer sheath to get to the ground wire.
- Conduit, where you can add a ground wire (again, it should have been there all along, and if it is metal conduit then that conduit itself should be a ground).

If all else fails, yes you can run a ground wire to another ground elsewhere. It does need to match the circuit - i.e., if this is a 15A circuit then anything 14 AWG or larger will do, but if it is a 20A circuit then the ground should be at least 12 AWG and the ground you're connecting to should be on a 20A or larger circuit.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the quick responses!